# Move sidebar widget to right sidebar

Tags: html, css

On my webpage: http://moneynest.co.uk/how-to-invest-your-money.html

I have the following sidebar widget:

```
<div class="col-md-4">



                <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
   <div class="blogcta">
<h3 class="hidden-xs">Aged 20-30? Get freedom from money frustration. It's easier than you think.</h3>
<h3 class="hidden-md hidden-lg" style="font-size: 150%;">Aged 20-30? Get freedom from money frustration</h3>
<h4 class="hidden-xs">
Take our free Jumpstart Your Finances class to
kick start your financial future:
</h4>
<h4 class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
  With Our Free 'Jumpstart Your Finances' Class
</h4>
 <div class="text-center blogctahere"><button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="d912bc07-505a-4835-a9f8-4a47449fc2ab" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Start Class Now</button></div><div id="popular-articles">
<p class="popular-articles-text">Popular articles</p> 
</div>
    </div>   </div>

</div>
```

How do I get this out of my Footer into my right sidebar?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: why don't you just use three columns and put the sidebar in the third column. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a col-g-4 div alongside your col-lg-8 div and paste the widget in there.